# How to add Application Insights to existing QnAMaker app

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-qna-maker

I have an existing QnAMaker app which presumably was created without AppInsights. I need to add one to get some logs and analytics.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are You using it through something like a bot or a webapp or just the qna maker ?

Answer (score 2):

You should configure it via the related webapp.

If your QnAMaker app's name is myapp1, and you should find the related azure webapp named myapp1, then in the Configuration -> Application settings, add the 3 settinigs:

`UserAppInsightsAppId` / `UserAppInsightsKey` / `UserAppInsightsName`.

For the value of `UserAppInsightsAppId`, please follow [this doc](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/solution-accelerators/tutorials/view-analytics/2-get-application-insights-application-id/).

For the value of `UserAppInsightsKey`, please follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-new-resource#copy-the-instrumentation-key).